# Correct syntax of WITH RESULT SETS () AS OBJECT(table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When using sp_execute_external_script I can't manage to find the correct syntax for the WITH RESULT SETS option, to store the result set in a table.

Here is the syntax given in the doc

```
sp_execute_external_script   
@language = N'language' ,   
@script = N'script',  

@input_data_1 = ] 'input_data_1'   
[ , @input_data_1_name = ] N'input_data_1_name' ]   
[ , @output_data_1_name = 'output_data_1_name' ]  
[ , @parallel = 0 | 1 ]  
[ , @params = ] N'@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ] [ ,...n ]'  
[ , @parameter1 = ] 'value1' [ OUT | OUTPUT ] [ ,...n ]  
[ WITH <execute_option> ]  
[;]  

<execute_option>::=  
{  
  { RESULT SETS UNDEFINED }   
| { RESULT SETS NONE }   
| { RESULT SETS ( <result_sets_definition> ) }  
}  

<result_sets_definition> ::=   
{  
    (  
     { column_name   
       data_type   
     [ COLLATE collation_name ]   
     [ NULL | NOT NULL ] }  
     [,...n ]  
)  
| AS OBJECT   
    [ db_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ]   
    {table_name | view_name | table_valued_function_name }  
| AS TYPE [ schema_name.]table_type_name  
}
```

But I get an error when writing

```
WITH RESULT SETS 
((
    [IDENTIFIANT] VARCHAR(50),
    [DATE] date,
    [CORPUS] NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS OBJECT [databasename].[dbo].[tablename]);
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. As the grammar shows, you can *either* have `WITH RESULT SETS ((...))` *or* `WITH RESULT SETS (AS OBJECT ...)`, but not both at the same time (unless you have more than one result set, but then you need to separate them with a comma). Both together wouldn't make sense: only one specification for the result set can can apply. `WITH RESULT SETS` does not store anything anywhere -- it only specifies the shape of a dynamic result set. If you want to store it into a table, use `INSERT ... EXEC`, but then `RESULT SETS` is not required (or allowed).

Comment: Oooh yeah my bad, brainfreeze, I forgot the | stood for "or" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by Jeroen Mostert : you can either have WITH RESULT SETS ((...)) or WITH RESULT SETS (AS OBJECT ...), but not both at the same time.